# Spray json trait formatter with nested subclasses

Tags: json, scala, spray-json

My use-case is the following:

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

sealed trait TestT
case class A(a: String) extends TestT
case class B(b: String) extends TestT
case class C(c: TestT) extends TestT

case class Parent(list: Seq[TestT])


implicit val aFormat = jsonFormat1(A)
implicit val bFormat = jsonFormat1(B)

implicit lazy val cFormat = lazyFormat(jsonFormat1(C))


implicit object TestTJsonFormat extends RootJsonFormat[TestT] {
  override def read(json: JsValue) = {
    if(json.asJsObject.fields.get("a").isDefined) {
      json.convertTo[A]
    } else if(json.asJsObject.fields.get("b").isDefined) {
      json.convertTo[B]
    } else if(json.asJsObject.fields.get("c").isDefined) {
      json.convertTo[C]
    } else {
      ???
    }
  }

  override def write(obj: TestT) = {
    obj match {
      case a:A => a.toJson
      case b:B => b.toJson
      case c:C => c.toJson
      case _ => ???
    }
  }
}

implicit val pFormat = jsonFormat1(Parent)

val json = Parent(Seq(A("test"), B("test2"), A("test3"))).toJson
println(json)
val p = json.convertTo[Parent]
println(p)
```

The main problem is that I can't make a formatter for C if I don't have a formatter for TestT. But I can't make a formatter for TestT because I don't have a json.convertTo for C yet...

Any idea how can I resolve this form of dependency?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/milessabin/spray-json-shapeless

Serialize whole classtrees.

```
object MyFormats extends DefaultJsonProtocol with FamilyFormats {
  // gives a slight performance boost, but isn't necessary
  implicit val MyAdtFormats = shapeless.cachedImplicit[JsonFormat[TestT]]
}
import MyFormats._
```